# style box with line

Tags: tcolorbox

i want to create beautiful box with parallel line.
Please see attached image

My minimal Coding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\tikzset{fancytitle/.style ={fill=red, text=white}}


  \newtcolorbox{Mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
    arc=4mm,
  colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!50!white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,
  title={#2},
  #1}

  \begin{document}

 \begin{Mybox}[width=5.4cm,height=2.4cm]{Title}
    \begin{center}

abc xyz
\end{center}
 \end{Mybox}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `\usepackage[tikz]`, which is unnecessary and has an incorrect syntax (`[...]` instead of `{...}`).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239841.

Comment: On page 4 of the manual of the `frcursive` package, there is a `macro` that draws lines as in a Seyes notebook. I don't know TeX well enough to be able to adapt it.  https://ctan.org/pkg/frcursive?lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to a large extent copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239841) but the `\parshape` stuff is inserted automatically with `before upper`. Of course, you can adjust the dimensions as you like and may change the number of lines of `\parshape` accordingly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{Mybox}[2][]{%
enhanced,top=0mm,left=2pt,right=2pt,
enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
fontupper=\normalsize,
  overlay unbroken and first={%
  \draw[fill=yellow]
   ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west) -| ++ (1,-2) 
   -- ++ (-0.5,0.3) -- ++ (-0.5,-0.3) -- cycle;
  \node[anchor=north west,text width=1cm-4pt,align=center] at ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west) 
  {#2}; 
},
breakable,arc=4mm,
colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,
width=\textwidth, 
before upper ={\parshape 5
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
0pt \hsize} ,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{Mybox}[width=5.4cm]{abc xyz}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text 
\end{Mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want literally horizontal lines, you can use `\hrulefill`. (However, in this case you may be better off without `tcolorbox` and draw the thing simply in plain Ti*k*Z.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{ic}
\newtcolorbox{Mybox}[2][]{%
enhanced,top=0mm,left=2pt,right=2pt,
enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
fontupper=\normalsize,
  overlay unbroken and first={%
  \draw[fill=yellow]
   ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west) -| ++ (1.6,-1.3) 
   -- ++ (-0.8,0.3) -- ++ (-0.8,-0.3) -- cycle;
  \node[anchor=north west,text width=1.6cm-4pt,align=center] at ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west) 
  {#2}; 
},
breakable,arc=4mm,
colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,
width=\textwidth,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{Mybox}[width=5.4cm]{abc xyz}
\vphantom{X}\hspace{1.8cm}\hrulefill{}\par 
\hspace{1.8cm}\hrulefill{}\par 
\hrulefill{}\par 
\hrulefill{}\par 
\hrulefill{}
\end{Mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]