# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]: tcbset

Tags: tcolorbox

I change code to tcbset for tcbposter from  topic: [style box with line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504948/style-box-with-line?noredirect=1#comment1275645_504948)

But this converted code is fail: "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

  \tcbset{
  mystylebox/.style 2 args={%
    enhanced,
    top=0mm,left=2pt,right=2pt,
    enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
    enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
    fontupper=\normalsize,
        %title={#1},
    overlay unbroken and first={%
        \draw[fill=yellow]
        ([xshift=16pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west) -| ++ (2,-2) 
        -- ++ (-1,0.3) -- ++ (-1,-0.3) -- cycle;
        \node[anchor=north west,text width=2cm-4pt,align=center] at ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west)
          {#2};
        },
breakable,arc=4mm,
colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,
width=\textwidth, 
before upper ={\parshape 5
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
1.2cm \dimexpr \hsize-1.2cm\relax
0pt \hsize}
        title={#1},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[poster = {columns=4, rows=7, width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.5\textheight,spacing=0.1mm}]

\posterbox[width=4.0cm,height=4.0cm,mystylebox={colframe=blue}{NAME}]{column=1, row=5, rowspan=0.7}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please help

Thanks

Comment: The `\node` command is *not* wrong here, but you are mixing many different things and it is not clear what you want to achieve. The way you set up things, `before upper` gets ignored.

Comment: @schroediner's cat. Thanks. You 're right. can you change your code in this case - for tcbset. Thanks

Comment: And in posterbox

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for `\node` was not correct:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\tcbset{
  mystylebox/.style 2 args={%
    enhanced,
    top=0mm,left=2pt,right=2pt,
    enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
    enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
    fontupper=\normalsize,
        title={#1},
    overlay unbroken and first={%
        \draw[fill=yellow]
        ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west) -| ++ (1,-2) 
        -- ++ (-0.5,0.3) -- ++ (-0.5,-0.3) -- cycle;
        \node[anchor=north west,text width=1cm-4pt,align=center] at ([xshift=6pt,yshift=12pt]frame.north west)
          {#2};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[poster = {columns=4, rows=7, width=0.5\textwidth, 
height=0.5\textheight,spacing=0.1mm}]       
    \posterbox[width=4.0cm,height=4.0cm,mystylebox={colframe=blue}{NAME}]{column=1, row=5, 
    rowspan=0.7}{xxx yyy}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. can you please edit to create same box in my attached image? Thank